# mysql_install_db giving error

Tags: mysql, database, installation, redhat, database-administration

I have downloaded the **mysql-5.1.38-linux-x86_64-glibc23.tar.gz** from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads)

and then i have executed it by using below command

```
groupadd mysql

useradd -g mysql mysql123

cp mysql-5.1.38-linux-x86_64-glibc23.tar.gz /home /mysql123/

su - mysql123

tar -zxvf mysql-5.1.38-linux-x86_64-glibc23.tar.gz

mv mysql-5.1.38-linux-x86_64-glibc23 mysql

mkdir tmp

cd mysql/

mv suppport-files/my-medium.cnf my.cnf

cp support-files/mysql.server bin/
```

and then i have edited the my.cnf and set the basedir and datadir to **/home/mysql123/mysql** and **/home/mysql123/mysql/data** and innodb_home_dir and logfile directory to datadir

Now edited mysql.server and set the datadir and basedir in them properly

and then initiated mysql_install_db as

```
[mysql123@localhost mysql]$ ./scripts/mysql_install_db
./scripts/mysql_install_db: line 244: ./bin/my_print_defaults: cannot execute binary file
Neither host '127.0.0.1' nor 'localhost' could be looked up with
./bin/resolveip
Please configure the 'hostname' command to return a correct
hostname.
If you want to solve this at a later stage, restart this script
with the --force option
```

on seeing the error i thought it may be confused with basedir and executed the same as below

```
[mysql123@localhost mysql]$ ./scripts/mysql_install_db -–user=mysql123 -–basedir=/home/mysql123/mysql
./scripts/mysql_install_db: line 244: ./bin/my_print_defaults: cannot execute binary file
Neither host '127.0.0.1' nor 'localhost' could be looked up with
./bin/resolveip
Please configure the 'hostname' command to return a correct
hostname.
If you want to solve this at a later stage, restart this script
with the --force option
```

i am not gettin what is going internally and showing this kind of message

and i am sure that i have enough diskspace ( **df -h** ) and i have proper ownership ( **chown mysq123:mysql /home/mysql123/ -R**) and proper permissions ( **chmod 755 .**)

and the lines in mysql_install_db are like below
[image]

please any help to solve this problem is very useful ( and i have to follow the same installation process)

i am using redhat 6

Comment: I don't think your host file is the problem. Not for localhost anyway. Searched and found a reference to someone with what may be the same problem - looks like a bug in their case and they solved it. Might want to start from the bottom ;) [link](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44405)

Answer (score 1):

Neither host '127.0.0.1' nor 'localhost' could be looked up with
./bin/resolveip

Just add string in /etc/hosts

Answer (score 0):

Based on your prompt which identifies your host as 'localhost' in your screen shots it would appear that the program is designed to not accept that as a valid hostname.

Please change your hostname to something other than 'localhost'.

"Please configure the 'hostname' command to return a correct
hostname.
If you want to solve this at a later stage, restart this script
with the --force option"

Alternately, the above message suggests you can use the --force option to over ride this. But having a sensible hostname seems like the better path.

-HTH

Answer (score 0):

Please execute below steps to resolve your ip Address.

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/network
HOSTNAME=mybox

vi /etc/hosts

10.103.14.112 mybox.example.com mybox

/usr/bin/resolveip 10.103.14.112
```

logout from the box and login again.

It works fine.

Give a try.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and it was due to installing a 32bit MySQL in a 64bit system.  That became obvious when I ran `./bin/resolveip` and it said

`bash: ./bin/resolveip: No such file or directory`

Despite it existing and being executable.

Solution was to change to using a 64bit mysql.  In your case it would seem you need to try the opposite - try 32bit instead.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue simply because there was a discrepancy in my CNF file: the basedir was not set to my $MYSQL_HOME.