# Error running mysql_install_db: could not find ./bin/my_print_defaults

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I seem to be having an issue getting MySQL 5.6.1.5 to install from Source. I am running RHEL 6.

I was able to perform the `cmake`, `make`, and `make install` without issues.

I am attempting to run the `mysql_install_db` binary and when I do I get the following error:

> Fatal ERROR: Could not find ./bin/my_print_defaults
>
> If you compiled from source, you need to run 'make install' to copy the software
>       into the correct location ready for operation.
>
> If you are using a binary release, you must either bat at the top level of the
>       extracted archive, or pass the --basedir option pointing to that location.

So I did a check for `my_print_defaults` using `which my_print_defaults`, unfortunately it was not found on my machine.

I did a `locate my_print_defaults` as well just for the heck of it and said it was located in `/usr/bin/my_print_defaults`, however, when I checked `/usr/bin` for the binary, it was not actually there.

I would try to use `mysql_install_db --basedir=/usr/bin` but I know this won't work as the `which` and `locate` commands confirm `my_print_defaults` isn't on my machine.

I looked at [mysql_install_db giving error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719605/mysql-install-db-giving-error), but that error was not similar to this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please ignore question, I didn't bother to try running `find / -name my_print_defaults` and found it in `/usr/local/mysql/bin/`

Comment: This is a valid answer. Don't apologize for it.

Comment: This was exactly the answer to my problem. I was trying to do this via  the fonz fun-plug on a DNS-323 NAS.

Comment: why should anyone have to do this?  is mysql designed bad on purpose?

Answer (score 1):

I searched packages for `my_print_defaults` with

```
apt-file search my_print_defaults
```

If `my_print_defaults` is missing on your system (`which my_print_defaults`), first find out which db is installed with:

```
dpkg -l |grep -E 'maria|mysql'|grep ii|grep server
```

If you have installed mariadb, try reinstall mariadb:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall mariadb-server-core-10.1
```

If you don't find a solution with mariadb, swap back to mysql with

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
```