# FATAL ERROR: Could not find my_print_defaults (Installing MariaDB Binary Tarballs on Mac)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Running :

`/usr/local/mysql/mariadb-10.5.8/scripts/mysql_install_db.sh --user=mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql/mariadb-10.5.8`

Gives me the error :

```
FATAL ERROR: Could not find my_print_defaults
```

Please advise me on what I could do to solve this.

Comment: did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21146305/error-running-mysql-install-db-could-not-find-bin-my-print-defaults?

Comment: Why install this the hard way when things like [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org) exist?

Comment: my_print_defaults isn't in /usr/local/mysql/mariadb-10.5.8/bin/... I don't see a bin folder in it

Comment: cuz I am using the M1 computer and it has only partial support for them